# Trigger Plugin or Workflow when marketing list member has been removed

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

Im using Marketinglists in Dynamics CRM 2013 with MemberTyp Contact. 
When I remove one of these contacts, I want to trigger a workflow and/or plugin which is doing some logic - is this possible?
I guess I need the event which is fired when I remove a contact from the MarketingList.

I tried to develop a plugin with Post-Operation, Update on the Marketinglist entity, but I couldnt find a way how to get the specific contactc guid, which has been removed.

Does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a Plugin step on the `Disassociate` message. This is not registered to a specific entity and will fire anytime a disassociation event occurs.

Then in the plugin code you write should check to see if the relationship being disassociated is the one you are interested in (you can look this information up in CRM's metadata/system customizer):

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains(“Relationship”)) {

                    relationshipName = context.InputParameters[“Relationship”].ToString();

                 }                                   

                 // Check the “Relationship Name” with your intended one

                 if (relationshipName != “{YOUR RELATION NAME}”) {

                     return;

            }
```

For more details, include the source of the code: https://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/associatedisassociate-plugin-messages-in-crm/